# Disable UXTerm has keyboard shortcuts on uppercase letters

Tags: xterm

I just configured UXTerm in `~/.Xresources`. When I wanted to start using UXTerm, I noticed that some keyboard shortcuts are on Shift + , which is a total blocker.

I use [Neo2](https://www.neo-layout.org/) as my main keyboard layout. All the systems shortcuts expect that layout, even the disc encryption passphrase prompt. I am not sure whether this is relevant, though.

I identified the shortcuts Shift+X, Shift+Q, Shift+W and Shift+-. Shift+Q increases the font size, Shift+- decreases it. I am not sure what the others do, but I cannot enter uppercase W and X.

Is there a way to rebind or disable these shortcuts?

My configuration is:

```
*background:         #eeeeee
*color0:             #4c4c4b
*color1:             #af0000
*color2:             #008700
*color3:             #5f8700
*color4:             #0087af
*color5:             #878787
*color6:             #005f87
*color7:             #444444
*color8:             #bcbcbc
*color9:             #d70000
*color10:            #d70087
*color11:            #8700af
*color12:            #d75f00
*color13:            #d75f00
*color14:            #005faf
*color15:            #005f87
! *colorBD:            #FF0000
*colorBDMode:        false
! *colorUL:            Black
*colorULMode:        false
*cursorColor:        Black
*foreground:         Black

*renderFont: True
*faceName: Hack
*faceSize: 12
```

Comment: sounds like the window manager rather than xterm (or the shell).  See the xterm manual page for default translations.  Fontsize in xterm is bound to *keypad* keys, not "W", etc.

Comment: Window Manager is kwin; desktop environment is KDE. I found the default keybindings at https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#h3-Default-Key-Bindings but struggle to understand those. How would I disable a specific one?

Comment: You can disable groups of related translations using the [`omitTranslation`](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#Application-Resources:omitTranslation) resource, e.g., `*omitTranslation:shift-fonts`

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much! If you would write an answer, I could accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The illustration of the [Neo2](https://www.neo-layout.org/) keyboard does not show the numeric keypad used with a PC-style keyboard, but the comment about

> Shift+Q increases the font size, Shift+- decreases it.

sounds as if the Neo2 keyboard layout is interfering with xterm's [*default key-bindings*](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#h3-Default-Key-Bindings) for changing the font size:

```
               Shift~Ctrl <KeyPress> KP_Add:larger-vt-font() \n\
               Shift Ctrl <KeyPress> KP_Add:smaller-vt-font() \n\
               Shift <KeyPress> KP_Subtract:smaller-vt-font() \n\
```

You can tell xterm to omit groups of related (default!) key bindings using the [**`omitTranslation`**](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#Application-Resources:omitTranslation) resource.  These form the **`shift-fonts`** group, e.g.,

```
*omitTranslation:shift-fonts
```

The manual page describes each of the groups; the [implementation](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/xterm-snapshots/blob/master/charproc.c#L13834) might be useful reading.